# RuntimeError (No resource_class found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook, devise-token-auth, omniauth-google-oauth2

Creating a `Rails API` using `Devise_token_auth` gem and trying to make it omniauthable to be able to login through google and facebook. Following this :- [github](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/1020). This error has been registered with no solution yet [Here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/907) .
My error :-

```
`Started POST "/omniauth/facebook/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-12 13:26:08 +0530 
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController#redirect_callbacks as */* 
Parameters: {"provider"=>"facebook"} 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


   RuntimeError (No resource_class found):    
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in 
`configure_permitted_parameters'
```

Now my configure_permitted_parameters contain some body parameters i need in signup to be present and are not to be ignored.
What should be my technique/approach to ignore this and check my API for `devise: omniauthable`

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, Did you find any solution? Regards